# java 9 b132 eclipse neon setsecuritymanager cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, securitymanager, java-9

Using java 1.9 (b132), Eclipse Neon (4.6.0), I am working through a large legacy java client front end project in preparation for java 9. Most of the code works, but this problem I cannot resolve. I have added the following to the eclipse.ini:

```
...
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk-9/bin/javaw.exe
...
--add-modules=java.se.ee
```

My problem can be easily replicated in a simple example in Eclipse:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setSecurityManager(null);
    }
}
```

Eclipse will not build this, giving: 'The type java.lang.SecurityManager cannot be resolved...'

Tried adding -Djava security.manager to the eclipse.ini but that did not load.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you installed the java 9 beta plugin?

Comment: Thanks for replying - yes, plugin added to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 9 release candidate and Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1a, this should be fixed. You can find out how to configure eclipse with Java 9 [here.](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9)

---

Moreover to access :

```
java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(null);
```

you don't need to use `--add-modules java.se.ee` since the `java.lang` package is exported by the `java.base` module of JDK itself. So the code sample as shared in the question should compile with a sample `module-info` like the following as well:

```
module your.new.modules { }
```